# Memory Leak in Oracle Client 10.2.04 for 64bit ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, oracle, memory, client, memory-leaks

Does anybody know of Memory Leak in Oracle Client 10.2.04 64bit?

We use in on ASP.NET application running on Windows 2008 server with
System.Data.OracleClient and our process is growing to 2.4GB withing few days!

Comment: Have you had a look on metalink?

Answer (score 1):

Can you test this on a 32bit client somewhere? Has the app worked in other environments, e.g., is this a sudden onset associated with migrating to 64 bit software? Is this an in-house developed app? Before I would point to Oracle, I'd suspect my own code. Particularly with something as egregious as this appears to be! Make sure there are no loops that open cursors inside and never close them.